# Recurly js Card Element Event handling Script Required

Tags: javascript, event-handling, payment-gateway, recurly

Recurly js Card Element event handling

User should be able to continue entering credit card, without needing to click to MM/YY, etc. Continuing to type should move to next relevant box through js.
Because tried with external script is not working for reculry element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets complicated when you consider that not all credit cards have the same number of digits in the card number. American Express, for example, is of the form: XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX (15 digits) whereas a Visa/MasterCard is of the form: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX (16 digits)

Comment: Yaa, It's too complicated work. So sent an request to reculy team for this activity. Thanks for given information @Doug Miller

Comment: Has this been solved? for a company of their size this seems ridiculous and amateur